# How to make Tumblr photo un-clickable

Tags: html, css

I use a single Tumblr post as my homepage / splash page (http://winder.space)- I'll never add another post.

But, it is a photo post; and I'm trying to figure out how to edit the CSS theme so that the photo is NOT clickable whatsoever. Any ideas?

I cannot simply delete the {LinkOpenTag} and {LinkCloseTag}s, which appear twice (once under `<div class="post photo">` and once under `<div class="post panorama">`).

Thanks!

Comment: The link you have posted is broken.

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy I unbroke the link for you.

Answer (score 5):

```
#object>a {pointer-events: none;}
```

will do the trick.

However, I have to advise on creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example here, on StackOverflow, as after you would have applied the fix on your website, your question will be a lot less helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pointer-events` to disable events on photo :-)

`style="pointer-events: none;"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enter the following rule in your stylesheet:

```
a[href="http://winder.space/image/156268872048"] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```